# Pass input->post data array into another form

Tags: codeigniter

i want to pass my inputted data as an array into another form that will converted into pdf, here is my controller code

**Controller**

```
public function printReport(){
        $data['report'] = array(
        'date' => $this->input->post('date'),
        'applicant_name' => $this->input->post('applicant-name'),
        'permit_type' => $this->input->post('permit-type'),
        'project_type' => $this->input->post('project-type'),
        'total_amount' => $this->input->post('amount-paid'),
        ); // pass data to the view
        $
        $applicant = $this->input->post('date');

        // As PDF creation takes a bit of memory, we're saving the created file in /downloads/reports/
        $pdfFilePath = "C:/Users/Kevin/Desktop/$applicant.pdf";


        if (file_exists($pdfFilePath) == FALSE){
            ini_set('memory_limit','32M'); // boost the memory limit if it's low <img src="http://davidsimpson.me/wp-includes/images/smilies/icon_wink.gif" alt=";)" class="wp-smiley">
            $html = $this->load->view('print-report', $data, true); // render the view into HTML

            $this->load->library('pdf');
            $pdf =$mpdf=new mPDF('utf-8', 'LEGAL');
            $pdf->WriteHTML($html); // write the HTML into the PDF
            $pdf->Output($pdfFilePath, 'I'); // save to file because we can
        }

    }
```

**Views**

```
<?php foreach ($report as $row):?>

<li><?php echo $row->applicant_name;?></li>

<?php endforeach;?>
```

it returns no result.

Comment: I guess this code has problem `$pdf = $mpdf=new mPDF('utf-8', 'LEGAL');` ? `=` can't be before `new`.

Comment: in your view : $row["applicant_name"]; It's an array, not an object.